# how can you replace characters in a string under the condition re.IGNORECASE

Tags: python, python-re, text-processing

```
sentence = 'this is a book.pdf'

sentence.replace( 'pdf' or 'PDF' ,'csv' )

sentence.replace('pdf','csv',re.IGNORECASE)
```

how can i replace the characters under the condition

- specified such as Pdf or PDF
- or Ignoring cases all together

Comment: how about using lower() for the sentence i.e. sentence.lower().replace(...) ?

Comment: you should explicitly state that case sensitvity is not actually important, and your actual goal is replacing any file extension with .csv, which is another question with a very large amount of duplicates.  This is a case of [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) along with an an ambiguously stated goal that does not and will not match with its answers nor keywords.  This would no doubt pollute search results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks as if you want to truncate any file extension found and add `.csv`.  I would recommend using `\w{1,5}` (one to five word chars) instead of `\w+` (one or more), because of the case of files named `an12n512n5125.1125n125n125` which I've had in my own file blobs often.

Match period followed by one or more alphanumeric characters at the end of string ($) and replace with .csv.  Case sensitivity no longer matters:

```
import re
sentence = 'this is a book.pdf'
ext2 = 'csv'
sentence = re.sub(rf'\.\w+$', f'.{ext2}', sentence)
```

slice end of string, lowercase compare it to .pdf, and replace .pdf with .csv.  Using string interpolation (f"") for customizable extensions

```
sentence = 'this is a book.pdf'
ext1 = 'pdf'
ext2 = 'csv'
sentence = sentence[:-4]+f'.{ext2}' if sentence[-4:].lower()==f'.{ext1}' else sentence
```

Using regex with $ to match end of string with re.IGNORECASE.  Using string interpolation for customizable extensions

```
import re
sentence = 'this is a book.pdf'
ext1 = 'pdf'
ext2 = 'csv'
sentence = re.sub(rf'\.{ext1}$', f'.{ext2}', sentence, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

Comment: The initial solution is not good practice as it assumes you know were .pdf is located, but the latter is more plausible

Comment: I don't understand that assertion; is the use case not for file extensions?  file extensions must be at the end of the string, so you would want to explicitly only allow it at the end of a string, which is the reasoning for using [:-4].  Unless you want to allow .pdf anywhere in the string, which in my own usage is actually a source of false positives.  such as (a real example) PDFEscape.exe => csvEscape.exe would cause issues.  If for the case of something like: file.pdf.zip is also needed, a slightly more complicataed regex to account for that would be needed

Comment: If this is a simple batch script where all your file names are known to be within the domain that .lower works, there's no reason not to just use .lower.  It really has nothing to do with "best practice" rather than, if you're just creating a .bat/.sh script or something similar for a restricted use case, cutting this corner doesn't matter.

Comment: oh yes,I get what you mean now

Answer (score 0):

I’m going to assume you are doing this to a string

```
sentence = sentence.lower()
```

Better yet just `sentence.lower()` where you are using sentence next could do the trick hard to say without more context.

Comment: authough not best practice , it definitely shortes the code and works well

Comment: Agreed with more context about what it is used for a better example could be given

Comment: @DanielButler I think it's fair to say that lowercasing the entire filename is in the majority of use cases not the intended result and could cause mangling of filenames.  The only valid cases are if you actually need it in lowercase or you are using it only as an intermediate checking string (whereas OP is assigning it to a variable "sentence" which implies it will be reused in a language context where case sensitvity is probably explicitly needed)

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this for multiple kinds of files then you can find the index of the period(.), delete everything after it and add the file extension to the end

```
sentence = sentence - sentence[sentence.index(".")+1:]
sentence += "csv"
```

Comment: what if you have multiple dots in between is there a way of specifying the last dot

Comment: use `.rindex` to get last index of